# How to convert SQLite date format to Matplotlib date format

Tags: python, sqlite, matplotlib

I have a series of SQLite dates of the form '2014-04-03 13:50:47'. I am trying to plot some data I sorted from the SQLite database but the date format is not compatible with Matplotlib. Would anyone have any incite as to what i would need to do to change both '2014-04-03 13:50:47' and '2014-04-03' into Matplotlib compatible values?

Thanks!

```
class performancePlot(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initPlot()


    def initPlot(self):
        baseFigure = Figure(figsize=(4, 4), dpi=100, frameon=True, edgecolor='none')
        subPlot = baseFigure.add_subplot(111)

        subPlot.plot([u'2014-04-03', u'2014-04-02', u'2014-04-01', u'2014-03-27', u'2014-03-24'], [219.0, 220.0, 218.0, 218.0, 219.0])
        subPlot.axhline(y=5, linewidth=1, color='g', linestyle='--')
        subPlot.axhline(y=5 + 2, linewidth=1, color='g', linestyle='--')
        subPlot.axhline(y=5 - 2, linewidth=1, color='g', linestyle='--')
        subPlot.axhline(y=(5 + (2 * 2)), linewidth=1, color='g', linestyle='--')
        subPlot.axhline(y=(5 - (2 * 2)), linewidth=1, color='g', linestyle='--')
        figureCanvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(baseFigure, master=self)
        figureCanvas.show()
        figureCanvas.get_tk_widget().grid(column=0, row=0)

root = Tk()
#root.geometry("250x150+300+300")
plotTest = performancePlot(root)
plotTest2 = performancePlot(root)
plotTest3 = performancePlot(root)

plotTest.grid(column=0, row=1)
plotTest2.grid(column=1, row=1)
plotTest3.grid(column=2, row=1)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Shouldn't be an issue, mind post a section of your data? Either SQL or CSV?

Comment: The above dates come from an SQLite database